# How to get the name of the file my output is redirected to?

Tags: cmd, powershell-2.0

In a .CMD file I have the following line

```
powershell -file somescript.ps1 1>mylogfile.log 2>&1
```

I need in the script the recover the complete filename (path+name+ext) of the logfile the output is redirected to.

The solution I found so far is, at the top of the script, run `handle.exe`, get all the files open by my process and find the one open twice (because of `1>mylogfile.log 2>&1`).

Do you have a better solution?

### EDIT

I need to send by mail the path+name of the log from within the script.

Unfortunately, the path+name of the log is computed in the .CMD (the ext will always be .log). And no, I cannot add a param to the script to pass the path+name of the file as a parameter because I cannot modify the CMD.

Comment: `%CD%\mylogfile.log` in CMD? Or `"$(Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path -Parent)\mylogfile.log"` in PowerShell? Please take a step back and describe the actual problem you're trying to solve instead of what you perceive as the solution. What do you need this for?

Comment: Either do the redirection *inside* the PowerShell script (so that your script already knows the path and can actually close the file before trying to mail it), or put the mail code in a separate script and pass it the full path to the log file.